# QuerySyntaxException while upgrading to hibernate 5.1

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, compiler-errors, hibernate-5.x

I was working with hibernate 4.3 using annotations and I did not had any mapping issue.I migrated to hibernate 5.1 and I have mapping issues.

I check my DAO and query is using same name as that of my entity class that is the solution everyone suggest.

This is my entity class

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "__maintenance", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "name"))
public class __Maintenance implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7217691607923908432L;

    private int idMaintenance;
    private int version;
    private String storyNumber;
    private String name;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
    private String comments;

    public __Maintenance() {
    this.version = 1;
    }

    @Deprecated
    public __Maintenance(String storyNumber, String name) {
        this.storyNumber = storyNumber;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Deprecated
    public __Maintenance(String storyNumber, String name, Date startDate, Date endDate, String comments) {
        this.storyNumber = storyNumber;
        this.name = name;
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.endDate = endDate;
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

    @Column(name = "idMaintenance", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getIdMaintenance() {
        return this.idMaintenance;
    }

    public void setIdMaintenance(int idMaintenance) {
        this.idMaintenance = idMaintenance;
    }

    @Column(name = "version", nullable = false)
    public int getVersion() {
        return this.version;
    }

    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    @Column(name = "story_number", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getStoryNumber() {
        return this.storyNumber;
    }

    public void setStoryNumber(String storyNumber) {
        this.storyNumber = storyNumber;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "start_datetime", length = 19)
    public Date getStartDate() {
        return this.startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "end_datetime", length = 19)
    public Date getEndDate() {
        return this.endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    @Column(name = "comments", length = 65535)
    public String getComments() {
        return this.comments;
    }

    public void setComments(String comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }
```

And this is my query

```
        String query = "";
        query += "select m from __Maintenance m";
        query += "  where m.name = :name ";
        query += " order by ";
        query += "   m.startDate desc, m.idMaintenance desc";
        return super.list(query, "name", name);
    }
```

Following is my exception

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: __Maintenance is not mapped [select m from __Maintenance m  where m.name = :name  order by    m.startDate desc, m.idMaintenance desc]
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:79)
>       at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:218)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:76)

Comment: Your table is called `@Table(name="__maintenance, ..."`and you are selecting in  `__Maintenance`

Comment: Isn't it the name of entity class we need for selecting?

Comment: Does your class have an @Entity annotation?

Comment: The way you wrote your query it looks like you are just selecting from a table with the name "__Maintenance" nothing else

Comment: Yes I have @ entity and the main thing is with this annotation this thing is working with hibernate 4.3

Comment: Did you try lower case `__maintenance` in your query?

Comment: That also raise the same exception.

Comment: the last thing I can think of is to specify the whole package in your query like `com.package.__Maintenance`

Comment: It din't help.Thank you for helping though

Answer (score 1):

It seems the table is missing in the configuration. Is the table declared in persistence.xml or javaconfig file?

Comment: Table is mentioned in hibernate.cfg.xml. The thing is there is no mapping issue when I worked with hibernate 4.3